# Unable to install raw-socket@1.2.6 using the npm 3.10.10

Tags: node.js

I tried to install raw-socket [1.2.6] module in nodejs using the npm. When I am trying to install the module, got the following error..

```
Node version : 6.11.3

NPM version : 3.10.10

[test@test node_modules]$ npm install raw-socket2

> raw-socket2@1.2.6 install /home/test/node_modules/raw-socket2
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/test/node_modules/raw-socket2/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/raw/src/raw.o
In file included from /home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/node.h:42,
         from ../../nan/nan.h:24,
         from ../src/raw.cc:4:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:345: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: In constructor ‘v8::MaybeLocal<T>::MaybeLocal()’:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:362: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘bool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::IsEmpty() const’:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:369: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘bool v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocal(v8::Local<S>*) const’:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:373: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘bool v8::WeakCallbackInfo<T>::IsFirstPass() const’:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:441: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: At global scope:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:481: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: In constructor ‘v8::Global<T>::Global()’:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:820: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: In constructor ‘v8::Global<T>::Global(v8::Global<T>&&)’:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:845: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘v8::Global<T>& v8::Global<T>::operator=(v8::Global<S>&&)’:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:857: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: At global scope:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:882: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:1119: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:1125: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> v8::Function::NewInstance(v8::Local<v8::Context>) const’:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:3279: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: At global scope:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:4499: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:4515: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<T> v8::MaybeLocal<T>::ToLocalChecked()’:
/home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:7544: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:111,
         from ../src/raw.cc:4:
../../nan/nan_new.h: At global scope:
../../nan/nan_new.h:24: error: template declaration of ‘v8::Local<T> Nan::imp::To’
../../nan/nan_new.h:24: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
../../nan/nan_new.h:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
../../nan/nan_new.h:24: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_new.h:29: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_new.h:34: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_new.h:39: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_new.h:66: error: ‘v8::Handle’ has not been declared
../../nan/nan_new.h:66: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_new.h:65: error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of ‘static v8::Local<v8::Context> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Context>::New(v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, int)’
../../nan/nan_new.h:85: error: ‘v8::Handle’ has not been declared
../../nan/nan_new.h:85: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_new.h:93: error: ‘v8::Handle’ has not been declared
../../nan/nan_new.h:93: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_new.h:92: error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of ‘static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(void (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), int)’
../../nan/nan_new.h:139: error: ‘v8::Handle’ has not been declared
../../nan/nan_new.h:139: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_new.h:151: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Handle’ with no type
../../nan/nan_new.h:151: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
../../nan/nan_new.h:151: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_new.h:152: error: ‘FTH’ has not been declared
../../nan/nan_new.h:152: error: ‘FTH’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_new.h:171: error: ‘v8::Handle’ has not been declared
../../nan/nan_new.h:171: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:191,
         from ../../nan/nan.h:111,
         from ../src/raw.cc:4:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::BooleanObject> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::BooleanObject>::New(bool)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:49: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::BooleanObject::New(bool)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:4009)
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: At global scope:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:56: error: ‘v8::Handle’ has not been declared
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:56: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Context> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Context>::New(v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, int)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:58: error: ‘tmpl’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:58: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: At global scope:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:79: error: ‘v8::Handle’ has not been declared
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:79: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Function> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Function>::New(void (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), int)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:82: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: At global scope:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:89: error: ‘v8::Handle’ has not been declared
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:89: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New(void (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), int)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:93: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:94: error: ‘signature’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static typename Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<T>::return_t Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<T>::New(int32_t)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:117: error: ‘To’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:117: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static typename Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<T>::return_t Nan::imp::IntegerFactory<T>::New(uint32_t)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:123: error: ‘To’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:123: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Uint32> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Uint32>::New(int32_t)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:128: error: ‘To’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:128: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Uint32> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Uint32>::New(uint32_t)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:134: error: ‘To’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:134: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: At global scope:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:156: error: ‘v8::Local<v8::RegExp> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::RegExp>::New’ is not a static member of ‘struct Nan::imp::Factory<v8::RegExp>’
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:156: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:156: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:156: error: ‘pattern’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:157: error: expected primary-expression before ‘flags’
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:157: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Script> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Script>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:166: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::Script> v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:1352)
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::Script> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Script>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::ScriptOrigin&)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:173: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::Script> v8::ScriptCompiler::Compile(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:1352)
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: At global scope:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:179: error: ‘v8::Local<v8::Signature> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Signature>::New’ is not a static member of ‘struct Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Signature>’
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:179: error: ‘FTH’ is not a member of ‘Nan::imp::Factory<v8::Signature>’
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:179: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::String> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::String>::New(const uint8_t*, int)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:206: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::String> v8::String::NewFromOneByte(v8::Isolate*, const uint8_t*, v8::String::NewStringType, int)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:2332)
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::String> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::String>::New(v8::String::ExternalStringResource*)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:217: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::String> v8::String::NewExternal(v8::Isolate*, v8::String::ExternalStringResource*)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:2371)
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: At global scope:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:228: error: ‘v8::Local<v8::StringObject> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::StringObject>::New’ is not a static member of ‘struct Nan::imp::Factory<v8::StringObject>’
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:228: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:228: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:228: error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:228: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::UnboundScript> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::UnboundScript>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:237: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::UnboundScript> v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnbound(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:1333)
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In static member function ‘static v8::Local<v8::UnboundScript> Nan::imp::Factory<v8::UnboundScript>::New(v8::Local<v8::String>, const v8::ScriptOrigin&)’:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:244: warning: ‘static v8::Local<v8::UnboundScript> v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnbound(v8::Isolate*, v8::ScriptCompiler::Source*, v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include/node/v8.h:1333)
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: At global scope:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:253: error: ‘NanNew’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:253: error: template declaration of ‘v8::Local<T> NanNew’
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:253: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:253: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:253: error: ‘h’ was not declared in this scope
   .
   .
   .
../../nan/nan.h:2112: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
../../nan/nan.h:2109: warning: ‘_NanGetExternalParts’ defined but not used




make: *** [Release/obj.target/raw/src/raw.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/test/node_modules/raw-socket2/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/test/node_module`enter code here`s/raw-socket2
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN watchdog@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN watchdog@1.0.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "raw-socket2"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! raw-socket2@1.2.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the raw-socket2@1.2.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the raw-socket2 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs raw-socket2
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls raw-socket2
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/test/node_modules/npm-debug.log
```

We tried the same in different version of nodejs. But, work fine in the version0.10.36.

Answer (score 0):

You're not installing `raw-socket`, you're installing `raw-socket2`, which is a fork of the former, but one that hasn't been maintained very well (and therefore doesn't install on more recent versions of Node.js).

The original [`raw-socket`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket) seems to work okay in Node 8 (although the compiler does emit various warnings during installation, but warnings aren't errors).

Comment: While installing raw-socket .... we get the following error, npm install raw-socket

> raw-socket@1.5.1 install /home/test/node_modules/raw-socket
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/test/node_modules/raw-socket/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/raw/src/raw.o
In file included from ../src/raw.h:23,
                 from ../src/raw.cc:6:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:43:3: error: #error This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler
In file included from /home/test/.node-gyp/6.11.3/include

Comment: _"...requires a C++11 compiler"_. So do you have one installed?